# error_log not working as expected

Tags: php, error-handling, error-logging, error-log

I have the following basic code:

```
<?php

    //http://localhost/error_log.php
    echo "write to the error_log";
    error_log("error_log entry");
    //error_log("error_log entry",0);

?>
```

When I navigate to this page, I see `write to the error_log` in the browser.  It even appears in the access_log `/var/log/apache2/access.log`.

```
[my ip here] - - [18/Jan/2013:09:18:54 +0000] "GET /error_log.php HTTP/1.1" 200 314 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11"
```

but when I check the error_log i.e. `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, I don't see either of the error_log messages.

Why are these not getting entered into the error_log?

Comment: The behavior would depend on the setting for the `error_log` configuration directive. What does `ini_get('error_log')` say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call it without a second parameter, this means default is 0

```
0   message is sent to PHP's system logger, using the Operating System's system logging mechanism or a file, depending on what the error_log configuration directive is set to. This is the default option.
```

Now it depends on the [configuration of error_log](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log).

If here is not "stderr", php will not log into the apache error log.

It seams to be "syslog" of this php send your log message to the [syslog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog).

Now it depends on how you [rsyslog.d](http://linux.die.net/man/5/rsyslog.conf) is configurated.

But have  look at folling logs

```
tail /var/log/syslog
tail /var/log/messages
tail /var/log/php
tail /var/log/php.log
```

You message should be in one of them.

Answer (score 0):

`error.log` does not log anything unless error_log.php page makes an error.

`access.log` loges all the events that Apache Server process

That is the reason why your `error.log` does not log the event

check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html for more info